# Oracle Select if value is smaller than before

Tags: oracle

i have table:

[image]

how do i select ID form this table when value after less than previous value (expected result is ID = B2 and C1 ). Thanks you

Comment: On what order basis? You do realize that in RDBMS a table is an unordered set of rows. You'll have to specify an order based on which one row is said to **before or after** another

Comment: order by TIME col, sir

Comment: There are `LAG` and `LEAD` functions in oracle which lets you query more than one row in a table at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function `lead` for to get the last row's value and check if current row's value is lesser than that. You can also use `lead` in similar way to get the value from next row.

```
select distinct ID
from (
    select t.*,
        lag(value) over (
            partition by ID order by time
            ) as last_value
    from your_table t
    ) t
where value < last_value;
```